# How to typeset --?

Tags: tex-core

So I have been writing report, and had to put two `-` in row. It typesets as one instead of two `-`. I remember as I read Stefan Kottwitz's Latex for beginners guide, he have mentioned about `--`, but hadn't said how to actually typeset two `-` in row. (I may be wrong but anyways)

So, code

```tex
\subsection{Тестування}
\paragraph{Пункт \code{а}}
Відкриємо термінал та попросимо програму вивести справку користувача.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/t1.1}
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/t1.2}
    \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Справка користувача, опція \code{--help (-h)}}
    \label{fig:help}
\end{figure}

Відштовхуючись від \cref{fig:help}, перевіримо решту опцій.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/t3.1}
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/t3.2}
    \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Опція \code{--file (-f)}}
    \label{fig:file}
\end{figure}
```

produces

[image]

How to typeset `--` as two minuses?

Comment: Just tried to put `----file` instead of `--file` it works. Bruh.

Comment: It depends on how `\code` is defined. If this is a macro that is verbatim, it should output two hyphens: `\verb{--file (-f)}`. But it seems that it is not, so you could try `-{}-` or `-\/-`. The problem is that `--` is taken as a ligature for an en-dash and `---` is taken as ligature for an em-dash. Therefore, if you write `----`, you won't get two hyphens but one em-dash and one hyphen, which might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: What's the reason for `\begin{figure}[H]` inside a `minipage`? And the `minipage` is also useless.

Comment: @egreg So I could put two figures side-by-side in other way? Can you tell me?

Comment: @JasperHabicht `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\ttfamily{#1}}`

Comment: `\includegraphics` for each figure with width `.5\linewidth` will make them side-by-side.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry Damn. Really. Thanks!

Comment: You may try `\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline}` with package `listings`, so `--` will be displayed as is.